# How do I remove all stale branches from Github?

Tags: git, github, github-api

We have a lot of branches that are inactive (the newest is 7 months old, the oldest is two years ago).
I'd like to remove all of those branches in bulk from the remote if no PR is still open for them.

Should I be using Github's API? Should I be using git using snippets like those provided in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325599/delete-all-branches-that-are-more-than-x-days-weeks-old)?
Is there some Github functionality I'm not familiar with that can help organize our repository?

Comment: I'd love to have this feature in Github. When you fork a repo with 100+ branches that's just clutter.

Comment: I've requested this feature, but so far it's crickets. Upvote if you're interested; https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/68425

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can certainly achieve this using the GitHub API, but you will require a little bit of fiddling to do it.

First, use the [list pull requests API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) to obtain a list of open pull requests. Each item in this list contains a `["head"]["ref"]` entry which will be the name of a branch.

Now, using the [get all references API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-all-references), list all of the references in your repository. Note that the syntax for branches in the Git Data API is slightly different than the one returned from the pull request API (e.g. `refs/heads/topic` vs. `topic`), so you'll have to compensate for this. The references API also returns tags unless you search just the `refs/heads/` sub-namespace, as mentioned in the docs, so be aware of this.

Once you have these two lists of branch refs, it's simple enough to work out which branches have no open pull requests (don't forget to account for `master` or any other branch you wish to keep!).

At this point, you can use the [delete reference API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#delete-a-reference) to remove those branch refs from the repository.

Comment: I wrote a Python script that does exactly this. It lists all existing branches that are referenced by at least 1 closed PR and in none open PRs.

https://github.com/simplesurance/utils/blob/master/git/stale_github_pr_branches.py

Answer (score 40):

You can right click on the browser after opening the stale branches and run this in the browser java script console.

*To delete all the stale branches*. i.e) this script *automatically clicks to the next page* and proceeds to delete stale branches in the next page.

```js
async function deleteStaleBranches(delay=500) {     
    var stale_branches = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Delete branch"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < stale_branches.length; i++)     {  
          stale_branches.item(i).click();
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));     
        }     
        const next = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Next Page"]');
        if(next) {         
            next.click();
            setTimeout(() => deleteStaleBranches(500), 500);
        } 
}  (() => { deleteStaleBranches(500); })();
```

To delete the *stale branches that is present in the current page* only:

```js
async function deleteStaleBranches(delay=500) {     
    var stale_branches = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Delete branch"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < stale_branches.length; i++)     {  
          stale_branches.item(i).click();
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));     
        }     
        
}  (() => { deleteStaleBranches(500); })();
```

Comment: This is cool, any way of only doing that for merged ones?

Comment: you can automatically do that though -> https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-the-automatic-deletion-of-branches

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('button[data-target="branch-filter-item.destroyButton"]').forEach(btn => btn.click())`

Comment: For those searching, this solution doesn't work for Gitlab, because after the first branch deletion, the page refreshes, and you are no longer on the Stale branches tab, but the Branches Overview tab. If that didn't happen, it would have worked with a minor modification to the string passed to 'querySelectorAll'.

Comment: 2022, need to update the selector and add a delay: `var stale_branches = document.getElementsByClassName('js-branch-delete-button');
for (var i = 0; i < stale_branches.length; i++) {
    stale_branches.item(i).click();
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
}`

Comment: thanks, but I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules` when I tried.

Comment: @LunaLovegood updated to be more browser-compatible here: https://gist.github.com/victorlin/9c0be8f2d3305eae4d7bb8c5907a9e17

Comment: Thanks @victorlin, I have updated the answer and credited to the gist link of yours.

Comment: added a loop to automove to next page. 
`async function deleteStaleBranches() {
    var stale_branches = document.getElementsByClassName('js-branch-delete-button');
    for (var i = 0; i < stale_branches.length; i++)
    {
        stale_branches.item(i).click();
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
    }
    await document.evaluate("//a[text()='Next']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
}
while(true){
await deleteStaleBranches();
}`

Comment: Hi Nahum, am not  a js pro, when I tried running the script that you have given i get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules", could you please let me know how we should run this script? I tried in firefox. The other scripts works in firefox.

Comment: FYI - The 2022 version still works in 06/2023!

Comment: If you have a ton of pages with stale branches, this addition did the trick for me!

`async function deleteStaleBranches(delay=500) {
    var stale_branches = document.getElementsByClassName('js-branch-delete-button');
    for (var i = 0; i < stale_branches.length; i++)
    {
        stale_branches.item(i).click();
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
    }
    const next = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination > a")[1]
    if(next) {
        next.click()
        setTimeout(() => deleteStaleBranches(500), 500)
    }
}

(() => { deleteStaleBranches(500); })();`

Comment: GitHub seems to have changed their layout. The first page doesn't have two buttons anymore (the first one is now just a <span> element). Replace document.querySelectorAll(".pagination > a")[1]; with Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".pagination > a")).slice(-1)[0]; to support both, the old and the new layout.

Comment: thanks Jonas, have updated the script after checking the current site. I think the best way forward would be via shell script making use of GH api calls

Answer (score 3):

I took a different tack from the other answers and just used good ol' `git` (and bash) to do the work:

1. Retrieve list of all branches using `git branch -r >~/branches.txt` (after setting `git config --global core.pager cat`)
2. Prune `~/branches.txt` of ones I want to **keep**
3. Call `git push <ref> --delete <branch>` on each one ...

```sh
for ref_branch in $(cat ~/branches.txt | head -n 5); do
    ref="$(echo "$ref_branch" | grep -Eo '^[^/]+')"
    branch="$(echo "$ref_branch" | grep -Eo '[^/]+$')"
    git push "$ref" --delete "$branch"
done
```

Note the use of `| head -n 5` to give it a try with only 5 at a time. Remove that to let the whole thing rip.

This will likely work on most `sh` shells (zsh, etc.) but not Windows; sorry.

Comment: Sounds like step 2 requires manual intervention which isn't scalable so this still needs better automation.

Comment: @electrovir could be done reasonably easily with a sed script using '/pattern/d'

Answer (score 1):

More safe option - delete all *merged* branches:

```js
async function deleteStaleBranches(delay=500) {
    let buttons = [];
    document.querySelectorAll(".State.State--merged").forEach((el) => {
        const butEl = el.parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelector("button");
        buttons.push(butEl);
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].click();
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
    }
}

(() => { deleteStaleBranches(500); })();
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following in the console to delete only merged and closed branches.

```js
async function deleteMergedBranches(delay=500) {
    var stale_branches = document.getElementsByClassName('State--merged');
    for (var i = 0; i < stale_branches.length; i++)
    {
        stale_branches[i].parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.js-branch-delete-button').click()
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
    }
}

(() => { deleteMergedBranches(500); })();
```

```js
async function deleteClosedBranches(delay=500) {
    var stale_branches = document.getElementsByClassName('State--closed');
    for (var i = 0; i < stale_branches.length; i++)
    {
        stale_branches[i].parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.js-branch-delete-button').click()
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Step 1 go to stale branches

`https://github.com/<space>/<repo>/branches/stale`

## Step 2 Run this script in the javascript console

```js
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function clickEvenElements() {
  const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.fakZEC')).reverse();
  
  for (let index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
    // Since we reversed the array, we need to adjust the index check
    // We check for odd index because the elements are in reverse order
    if (index % 2 === 1) {
      elements[index].click(); // Perform the click action
      await sleep(500); // Sleep for 1000ms or 1 second
    }
  }
}
async function doAll(x) {
  for (let index = 0; index < x; index++) {
    await clickEvenElements();
    document.querySelectorAll(".chXkIK")[1].click()
    await sleep(1000)
  }
}
doAll(1)
```

Change the number in `doAll` to how ever many pages you want to recur through

https://gist.github.com/chitalian/6220b31cf8b7dc011220e62f89f0a8e0