# How to delete branches older than 1 month that was merged to master programmatically in git?

Tags: git

Is there a command that is able to programatically remove branches older than 1 month and that was merged to master branch in one shot?

Comment: Since when do you count that month? Branch creation (in which case, you won't have that in git itself)? Date of the merge into master?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325599/delete-all-branches-that-are-more-than-x-days-weeks-old

Comment: If you check the link offered by @LazarNikolic you just need the first part to be "git branch --merged master" instead of simply "git branch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on top of the answer shared by @LazarNikolic ([Delete all branches that are more than X days/weeks old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325599/delete-all-branches-that-are-more-than-x-days-weeks-old)):

```
for k in $(git branch --merged master | sed /\*/d | grep -v "master\|HEAD\|->"); do 
  if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='1 month ago' -s $k)" ]; then
    git branch -D $k
  fi
done
```

Some background:

- `git branch --merged master` to only list branches that have been merged to `master`.
- `git log --before` to inspect log entries that are more than 1 month old. If any entries exist, for any merged branch, delete that branch.
- `grep -v "master\|HEAD\|->"` to block it from trying to delete master, "->", and HEAD, it will fail to delete them but there's no need to create that error to begin with.

Comment: Played with this, wouldn't this also delete master (and HEAD) if you don't `grep` them away?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using git version 2.25.1. The answer above did not work for me but this does.

```
# Purge branches older than 1 month
for k in $(git branch | sed /\*/d)
do 
    log "Found branch $k"
    if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='1 month ago' --grep='$k')" ]
    then
        git push -d origin $k &> /dev/null
        git branch -d $k &> /dev/null
        log "Purged branch $k"
    fi
done
```