# How to delete old git branches before 1 year?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I want to list all 1 year before git branches and then ask user to type YES tto delete all the listed branches.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$data_folder" == "test" ]]; then

        current_timestamp=$(date +%s)
        twelve_months_ago=$(( $current_timestamp - 12*30*24*60*60 ))

        for x in `git branch -r | sed /\*/d`; do

                branch_timestamp=$(git show -s --format=%at $x)

                if [[ "$branch_timestamp" -lt "$twelve_months_ago" ]]; then
                        branch_for_removal+=("${x/origin\//}")
                fi
        done

if [[ "$USERCHOICE" == "YES" ]]; then
        git push origin --delete ${branch_for_removal[*]}
        echo "Finish!"
else
        echo "Exit"
fi
```

Is this logic correct to list and delete all 1 year before git branches !!

Comment: Feed your text to `shellcheck.net` and fix the obvious issues before you worry about the next part.

Comment: Don't forget to add a shebang before you use shellcheck.net

Comment: I believe `git show` identifies blobs, trees, tags and commits only, not branches: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show.  For listing branches you should probably use `git branch --list`.

Comment: @JonathonS. : `git show` works fine with branch names. Actually : branches in git are just pointers to commits. See for example [this section of the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10325599/7976758

Answer (score 3):

The overall logic looks ok (there may be some issue in the script, for example the `fi` which closes the initial `if [[ "$data_folder" == "test" ]]; then` is missing from the code you pasted).

There are however ways to use `git` commands to list the data you want in one go :

- for scripting purposes, use `git for-each-ref` rather than `git branch` :

  ```
  # to list only refs coming from remotes/origin :
  git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin

  # to have names 'origin/xxx` you are used to :
  git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/origin

  # to have the ref name without the leading 'origin/':
  git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)" refs/remotes/origin

  # to have the timestamp of the latest commit followed by the refname :
  git for-each-ref --format="%(authordate:unix) %(refname:lstrip=3)" refs/remotes/origin
  ```

  see `git help for-each-ref` for more details
- you can ask `date` to compute the "1 year ago" for you : `date -d '1 year ago' +%s`,
  and use e.g `awk` to filter your output in one go :

  ```
  d1year=$(date -d '1 year ago' +%s)
  git for-each-ref --format="..." refs/remotes/origin |\
      awk '{ if ($1 < '$d1year') print $2 }'
  ```

Also note : you may want to check the `committerdate` rather than the `authordate`